# Compiler Warning C6385 - Win32Api - Windows GUI Application [SOLVED]

Tags: windows, c++11, winapi, warnings

I am getting some compiler warnings, but I don't know how to fix them. I couldn't find the answer myself.

```cpp
int64_t ID = 0;
ID = (int64_t)LOWORD(wParam) - 203;
std::wstring numbersPositive[] = { L"0", L"1", L"2", L"3", L"4", L"5", L"6", L"7", L"8", L"9" };
std::wstring numbersNegative[] = { L"-0", L"-1", L"-2", L"-3", L"-4", L"-5", L"-6", L"-7", L"-8", L"-9" };

TCHAR Text[MAX_CALCULATOR_OUTPUT_STRING] = { 0 };
GetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, Text, ARRAYSIZE(Text));
std::wstring WText = Text;
if (WText == L"0") {
    SetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, numbersPositive[ID].c_str());
} 
else if (WText[0] == L'-' && WText[1] == L'0' && WText.length() == 2) {
    SetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, numbersNegative[ID].c_str()); // Compiler Warning C6385
}
else {
    int64_t length = WText.length();
    if (length <= ARRAYSIZE(Text) - 2) {
        WText = WText + numbersPositive[ID]; // Compiler Warning C6385
        SetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, WText.c_str());
    }
    else {
        MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
}
```

> Warning   C6385   Reading invalid data from `numbersNegative`:  the readable size is `400` bytes, but `2613320` bytes may be read.

> Warning   C6385   Reading invalid data from `numbersPositive`:  the readable size is `400` bytes, but `2613320` bytes may be read.

vvv Working Code Below vvv

```cpp
    case 203: case 204: case 205: case 206:
    case 207: case 208: case 209: case 210:
    case 211: case 212:
    {
        int64_t ID = 0;
        ID = (int64_t)LOWORD(wParam) % 10;
        (ID >= 3 && ID <= 9) ? ID = ID - 3 : (ID >= 0 && ID <= 2) ? ID = ID + 7 : ID = 0;
        std::wstring numbersPositive[] = { L"0", L"1", L"2", L"3", L"4", L"5", L"6", L"7", L"8", L"9" };
        std::wstring numbersNegative[] = { L"-0", L"-1", L"-2", L"-3", L"-4", L"-5", L"-6", L"-7", L"-8", L"-9" };

        TCHAR Text[MAX_CALCULATOR_OUTPUT_STRING] = { 0 };
        TCHAR ErrorText[40] = { 0 };
        GetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, Text, ARRAYSIZE(Text));
        GetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, ErrorText, ARRAYSIZE(ErrorText));
        std::wstring WText = Text;
        std::wstring WErrorText = ErrorText;
        std::wstring temp1 = numbersPositive[ID];
        std::wstring temp2 = numbersNegative[ID];
        int64_t length = WText.length();
        if (WText == L"0" || WErrorText == L"Infinity" || WErrorText == L"Cannot Divide by Zero") {
            WText = temp1;
            SetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, WText.c_str());
        }
        else if (WText[0] == L'-' && WText[1] == L'0' && length == 2) {
            WText = temp2;
            SetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, WText.c_str());
        }
        else {
            if (length < ARRAYSIZE(Text) - 1) {
                WText = WText + temp1;
                SetWindowText(hCalculatorOutput, WText.c_str());
            }
            else {
                MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Add the tags for the language (_C_ ?) and environment (_Windows_?) to your question for better audience.

Comment: My guess is, the compiler doesn't know what possible values `wParam` might have so it assumes that `LOWORD(wParam)` could be as large as 65535, and then of course `numbersPositive[ID]` would be wildly out of range. You could probably silence the warning with something like `assert(ID >= 0 && ID < 10);`

Comment: Why is `ID` declared as a 64-bit integer when its value will never exceed that of a 16-bit integer? You should change `ID`  to be a `WORD` instead, as that is what `LOWORD()` returns.

Comment: @igo A debug assertion will not (and should not) silence a compiler warning. The code would need an `if` statement for that.